# Can Hazelcast be configured to use a specific NIC?

Tags: configuration, hazelcast

Is it possible to configure Hazelcast to connect its members using a specific NIC? I saw that it is possible to connect members of a cluster via specific ports as described in the [documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch12s02.html). But I cannot find anything regarding NICs.

EDIT: I am trying to configure this on the "client" side of the connection rather than the "server" side.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should configure the `interfaces` section (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/manual/html-single/index.html#interfaces), as well as the properties `hazelcast.socket.bind.any` and `hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any` (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/manual/html-single/index.html#system-properties)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am looking for how to establish the TCP connection using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int). Any ideas?

Comment: Hazelcast creates and manages connections (and therefore sockets) internally. You cannot create your own socket and pass it to Hazelcast.